# Problem setting up debug configuration to attach to a gdbserver in Vis.Code

Tags: debugging, gdbserver

I was trying to setup **debug configuration to attach to already running gdbserver**.

(ref used: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference)

[*Note. I can attach and debug with an arch specific gdb instance fine to the gdbserver*]

That's the **template** that has logic check deadlock.

```
{
    "name": "(gdb) Attach to gdbserver in QEMU",
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "request": "attach",
    "MIMode": "gdb",
    "miDebuggerPath": "/path/to/gdb/../../bin/mips-mti-linux-gnu-gdb",
    "miDebuggerServerAddress": "localhost: 1234",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/__out--MIPS64r6_MTI/vmlinux",
    // "processId": "${command:none}",
    // "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
    // "processId": "23739",
    "setupCommands": [
        {
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
        }
    ]
},
```

When **no "processId"** given, it complains:
[unable to parse process id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnzCH.png)

When **some valid "processId"** given (*and then some process also selected from the list, if demanded by UI*), it complains:
['processId' cannot be used with miDebuggerServerAddress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxbG3.png)

Does anyone know how to resolve this deadlock in VC debug config parsing logic or this is a bug?

Thank you.

Comment: In [VC bug discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/577) I found a reply from support that suggests using `"request": "launch"` instead of `"request": "attach"`. 
But if using `"request": "launch"` (*despite sounds a bit illogical, as we're attaching to already running process, just supplied with gdbserver i-face*) as advised, the DB session init breaks with complain:
`remote replied unexpectedly to 'vMustReplyEmpty': timeout`

Comment: Ok. After second try worked ;)
They need updating the instructions then (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference).
It sounds really illogical to use `"request": "launch"` to actually do the _attach_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. After several tries it worked ;)

Using the `"request": "launch"` (*despite sounds a bit illogical, as we're attaching to already running process, just supplied with gdbserver i-face*) without `"processId"` as advised in [#577 bug discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/577), the DB session was braking up initially with complain:
`remote replied unexpectedly to 'vMustReplyEmpty': timeout`, but eventually worked after repeated tries ;)

Note. For `"lanuch"` case, VC demanded also adding: `"cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"`

The VC+CPP-plugin support needs updating the instructions then (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference).
It sounds really illogical to use "request": "launch" to actually do the *attach* action :).